# что за ORM "io.requery"?

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте. Достался проект, в котором как я полагаю используется ORM:

```
import io.requery.Entity;
import io.requery.Key;
```

Подскажите что это за ORM?

Comment: Нашел небольшое упоминание, что это requery, и она может работать с rxandroid, но почему то доков не нашел

Comment: Первая же ссылка в google - [requery docs](https://github.com/requery/requery/wiki)